# Payment method for automatic charges when event is completed

Tags: flutter, dart, service, paypal, payment

I want to build an mobile app with flutter that gets payment when event is done.

for example, i call a taxi from an app and app is calculates payment from distance, time etc.when finish driving button tapped, app is gonna take payment from saved credit card immediately no 3d secure or anything.

my question is what is that payment method called, how can i implement that service (stripe, paypal etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate **Stripe payment services**.
There are two ways you can choose to start:

- Install and use Stripe via [Firebase Extensions](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments)
- Install and use Stripe via [Dart Packages](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe)

I recommend them as they are very well documented and supported by Flutter.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to know what is the method called that charges automatically from user like uber payment system

Comment: You want something like recurring billing or subscription management, it?

Comment: actually not, i saw this system on scooter apps, u pick a scooter somewhere and time starts counting and when you finish your driving, you lock your scooter and press finish driving button then app charges from your credit card how much that cost of driving depends on driving time. not like recurring because every driving session you charged different prices for say minute of driving 0.50$ if you finish your driving after 5 minutes it will cost 2.5$, 10 minutes driving 5$

Comment: I understood. It is possible to make this payment system with Stripe, in fact creating this business model that you want is not going to require something very specific in the payment business rule. It is basically informing the payment method how much the user should be charged, a value defined by another calculation method based on time and cost per minute or hour.

Answer (score 1):

With PayPal, charging from a user account on file is variously called "reference transactions with billing agreements" (Classic API), or reference / customer not present transactions with Vault in newer APIs.

To use reference transactions, the PayPal account must first be approved for it. You can contact the business support and explain the business need for the feature. Alternatively you look into getting PayPal's Braintree service which always has reference transactions enabled.

Provided reference transactions are approved and enabled on an account (which it must be emphasized is something the business side does, not a technical matter), PayPal can then guide you on which specific API to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i understood this method more business side than technical thing. Do stripe has this method ? unfortunately PayPal is not available in my country.